# Join table with another table in different database by name string

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I've got a database server in front of me, that consists of multiple databases. For the sake of simplicity lets just say there is a main database with a table Main that looks like the following.

```
Main.dbo.MainTable

| ID | Value | DBName |
| -- | ----- | ------ |
| 1  | 12912 | DBA    |
| 2  | 10113 | DBA    |
| 3  | 00197 | DBB    |
| 4  | 63512 | DBC    |
| 5  | 12312 | DBB    |
```

In the column DBName, the name of a database with more information regarding the entry is defined.
DBA, DBB, DBC and DBD all use the same schema.
I now need to join the Main Table with a table that is found in the other databases. To be exact I need the table from the defined DBName and join it to the main table on id = id.

```
DBA.dbo.SomeTable

| ID | Info 1| Info 2|
| -- | ----- | ----- |
| 1  | 82732 | 28192 |
| 2  | 23772 | 71277 |
| 3  | 13913 | 82831 |
| 4  | 02283 | 91028 |
| 5  | 92322 | 81297 |
```

I tried using variables and exec statements to get the table from the database name string, but that didn't work.
`declare @dbname nvarchar(100); exec('select @dbname = main.DBName from Main.dbo.MainTable main left join '+ @dbname +'.dbo.SomeTable other on main.ID = other.ID')`

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: The problem is your design here, not the SQL. If you need to dynamically reference other databases to get the data you need for a `JOIN`, things have gone very wrong.

Comment: This needs some brutal dynamic sql OR that you ahead of time join all external tables and then do a CASE WHEN thing. This is not how you design a database though

Comment: I can't change the DB, it was there before me and it will still be there after my death.

Comment: I'd suggest maintaining `VIEW`s that `JOIN` to *every single database* you'll ever need to, and then querying those `VIEW`s when you need to query all the databases. I hope performance isn't a desirable feature, as it likely won't be available.

Comment: If it was there before you, then there should already be code to handle what you need to do, otherwise what's the point of storing this stuff.

Comment: The problem is that every row point to some other db, this cannot be solved by dynamic sql, because dynamic sql is just a string you generate with code and run once. You can't run different string for different row. You could probably create some kind of CLR function which does this, but it won't be pretty either. If you just want to get some data, you could do a cursor that reads row by row and fetches data into some destination

Comment: *"but the problem is that I may only read the database"* Then create a new database where you can maintain these `VIEW`s with *x* number of `JOIN`s to many databases.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: There is no question in this post.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a big `UNION ALL` query, and add a fixed column for each sub-table so you can join on it.

```sql
select
  dbname = main.DBName
from Main.dbo.MainTable main
left join (
    SELECT *, 'DBA' AS DBName
    FROM DBA.dbo.SomeTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *, 'DBB'
    FROM DBB.dbo.SomeTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *, 'DBC'
    FROM DBC.dbo.SomeTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *, 'DBD'
    FROM DBD.dbo.SomeTable
) other ON main.DBName = other.DBName AND main.ID = other.ID;
```

Ideally put that derived table into a view to keep the logic in one place.

Comment: Using your answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69622645/44522) this could be also done in a dynamic SQL.

Comment: Correct but this example looked like it was a small fixed list of databases.

Comment: Sure. For a fixed list of databases, this is way better. Keep it simple, if possible...

Comment: Actually the amount of databases is not fixed and grows over time. So I'll take a look at Charlies other answer.